# Периодическое подвисает чтение данных из серийного порта

Tags: java, serial

Здравствуйте! Помогите здравой мыслью, как лучше организовать чтение данных из серийного порта? Порт читается в цикле до получения необходимых данных (строка с набором более 50 символов). Посылаю команду - получаю ответ. Всё отлично работает, но `br.readLine()` почему то периодически "клинит" (по этой причине цикл базируется на временном интервале в 30 секунд) что бы не затягивать процесс и при последующем "отвисании" он просто вырубает цикл. Пробовал проверять поток `available()` - но с ним почти всегда 0. Весь процесс происходит в AsyncTask. Подскажите, как добиться стабильного чтения данных из порта?

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mInputStream, "ISO-8859-1"));

Thread.sleep(1000);

while (((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) < 30000)){

if ((br.readLine())!= null) out = br.readLine();    

i++;    

System.out.println(i+" "+out);  

if (out.length() > 50) {result = out; br.close(); break;}

Thread.sleep(1000); 

}
```

Comment: Поищите возможность увеличить таймауты на чтение. Когда-то столкнулся с этим (но там программа на C была, все работало через WinAPI и функция SetCommTimeouts решила проблему)

Comment: Уважаемый @tutankhamun! Благодарю за наводку! Общение с устройством происходит через нативный модуль на C# там как раз можно сконфигурировать параметры чтения в строках: cfg.c_cc[VMIN] =   1; // read doesn't block и cfg.c_cc[VTIME]=   5; // 0.5 seconds read timeout

Comment: Сделал считывание в Thread - всё встало на свои места!